Is deploying upgraded Angular app as simple as copying file?
I have upgraded an Angular app from version 16 to 18.
Everything works fine on my local dev environment.
How do I deploy it to my prod environment?
Is it as simple as copying the files and all the dependencies in package.json will be automatically downloaded or do I have to install them one by one?

...how were you deploying the v16 one? Read https://angular.dev/tools/cli/deployment

I was deploying by copy pasting the deployment files

And why do you think that has changed in v18?

I am assuming you run ng build --prod or something similar to get your dist/
You can copy that to your production server.
